# Xamarin.Forms - Extra space between two StackLayouts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms XAML setup like following, but don't know why there's extra space between two `StackLayout` instances. I tried setting padding to 0 and margin to 0 but still there's space in between and at the end of the last `StackLayout`.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" HeightRequest="500" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" Margin="0" Padding="0">
          <Label Text="MyTest" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="500" Margin="0">
          <ListView x:Name ="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBinding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyName}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyValue}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Remove 'Padding="10,0,10,0"' it's adding padding between your stack layouts and in the end. I would suggest to rethink your layout in general, try to optimise it, currently you have 3 stack layouts maybe a grid will fit your needs better?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words and would show _where_ you are seeing the spaces and make it easier for us to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't set any `VerticalOptions` to the first StackLayout and this is why it's just wrapping the Label and leaving an empty space as you are setting the other StackLayout to VerticalOption as `CenterAndExpand`.

To fix this you have a few options options:

1: Set VerticalOption to FillAndExpand to the StackLayout containing the ListView

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="500" Margin="0">
      <ListView x:Name ="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBinding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyName}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyValue}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

2: Set VerticalOption to EndAndExpand to the first StackLayout with the Label and VerticalOption as StartAndExpand to the second StackLayout with the List.

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" Margin="0" Padding="0">
      <Label Text="MyTest" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="500" Margin="0">
      <ListView x:Name ="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBinding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyName}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyValue}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Test both and see which one better suits your design needs as each one will place the UI controllers differently.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Nice pointer, but none of them work with a listview stacked atop a grid... No luck for me then

Answer (score 2):

You Can Set Spacing of parent layout to -6.
Spacing is a value in device pixels which indicates the amount of space between each element. The default value is 6.0....

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I set spacing of the parent StackLayout to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try adding a negative Margin value.
I had a similar problem which I was able to solve by adding a Margin of -5 to the second layout.

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
    <StackLayout x:Name="lOne" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" />
    <StackLayout x:Name="lTwo" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="10"/>
</StackLayout>
```

lT had a space which I was able to see when adding Background colors.
When I added Margin="-5" to this the space was gone.